# Queuing servlet requests from the same HTTP Client?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a conventional servlet, (conforms to the [servlet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html) defined by Oracle/Sun). It receives high volume requests at times from hundreds of users, and in some of these cases, any HTTP client can launch multiple requests in rapid succession. Sometimes the servlet has not finished processing the first request from a HTTP Client when the second is received and has commenced processing. So, I want to be able to manage the processing of request by queueing them when they come from the same HTTP Client and process them in order. This is only an issue when requests are received from the same HTTP Client.

I had heard of [FilterChains](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html), but am not sure if this is appropriate for this situation. What is the most appropriate means to queue multiple requests from a user ?

Comment: I think you encountered this scalability issue and trying to solve this with your code. I suggest you to take a look at NIO servlet containers such as jetty.

Answer (score -1):

Create two frame in one HTML page. One main frame and another secondary frame.Do something such that whenever we send one request response should be redirected to secondary freme.
**I m not sure** it will work for your case. but i resolved this type of problem in my project. in which servlet processing was heavy weight .and i was not able to complete one servlet process.

Comment: Solving at the client is not an effective solution for this. The inherent problem will still remain. The servlet engine needs to be coded so that no matter what client sends the request, the servlet manager can handle it sensibly.

Comment: i think at server side u cant handle queuing. because it using multiple  threading.so all the execution will perform simultaneously. ..